# How to have multiple pages/layouts under the same endpoint in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I will preface this question by stating I am not a frontend developer.

I am developing a pet project, where I have a form, and when the form is submitted, the user advances to the next "stage".

For example, a user fills in some basic info, uploads a file, and then in the next page I render the info that the user filled in. I would like all of this to happen under the `/app` endpoint.

How does this look like in practice? What's the proper way of developing a page that has multiple "pages" so to say? What are the appropriate terms so I can google more about this?

Right now I have something that looks like this, but I really dislike it.

```
<script>
  let currentStep = 0;
  let maxSteps = 3;

  function handleNextStep() {
    if (currentStep < maxSteps) {
      currentStep++;
    }
  }

</script>

{#if currentStep === 0}
  <Form nextStep={handleNextStep} />
{:else if currentStep === 1}
  <Render nextStep={handleNextStep} />
{:else if currentStep === 2}
  <App />
{/if}
```

The problem with this is that if I refresh the page I will lose the "progress", and overall it doesn't look good I think.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a  [single page app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA)

Comment: The default web browser behavior is to lose all entered form data upon page refresh. If you don't want that you need to temporarily store it, for example in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). If you want it to work without client-side JS, then you need to use hidden input fields, so the second form contains the data entered in the first form in hidden input fields, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only issue is that you do not want to lose the persistent data (and you're as obsessed as I am about your code having to look beautiful at all times then first read through:
https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store

Then Add this:

```
// src/lib/store.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const currentStepState = writable(0);
```

A store ensures that the data stays put when refreshing or navigating.

Then Modify your code:

```
// your ParentComponent in your app 
// (no more script tag needed)
<Form />
<Render />
<App />
```

Then Lets Modify The Form Component

```
// your Form component
<script>
  import { currentStepState } from '$lib/stores.js';

  // Run this when ready to go to the next step
  const gotoNextStep = () => currentStepState.set(1);
</script>

{#if $currentStepState === 0}
  <h1>I'm only visible when the current step is: {$currentStepState}</h1>
{/if}
```

And Finally the Render Component

```
// Your Render component
<script>
  import { currentStepState } from '$lib/stores.js';

  // Run this when ready to go to the next step
  const gotoNextStep = () => currentStepState.set(2);
</script>

{#if $currentStepState === 1}
  <h1>I'm only visible when the current step is: {$currentStepState}</h1>
{/if}
```

...You get the idea by now :)

```
// Your App component
<script>
  import { currentStepState } from '$lib/stores.js';
</script>

{#if $currentStepState === 2}
  <h1>I'm only visible when the current step is: {$currentStepState}</h1>
{/if}
```

There you go, thanks for clarifying what you where looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! However, I would like to have multiple steps within the same endpoint (I am already using sveltekit)

Comment: Alright, thanks for clarifying. I've removed the irrelevant info in the Edit. 

Right now I made it so that each component looks at the store and decides for itself if it has to be displayed or not. And when ready they can increment the "currentStep" on their own. Now your parent component doesn't need to be concerned with any of that logic.

I personally prefer to keep logic in the parent so I know "why" I'm not seeing the Form component for example, but you can also do it this way to prioritize cleanliness over readability if that's preferred in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working on Single Page Application. if so, You need to maintain the application `state`.

e.g user upload data - is a one state.
if you don't have data in your state, you will show a `upload` screen otherwise you will display the `relevant` page / component.

(PS. this is not specific to `Svelte` but applicable to any UI Framework)

keywords for you to search are: -

1. single page app
2. UI state management lib ( e.g redux )
3. routing between pages/component.

hope this helps.